# Indicar uma coluna se existir em TODOS os elementos de outra SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu tenho a seguinte questão : " Indique o "name3" que estão em TODOS os "name" .

E tenho 4 tabelas que estão abaixo

```
-- A (name,Num2, local)
insert into A values ('Favela',1,'WE');
insert into A values ('Lamosa',2,'NA');
insert into A values ('Luz',3,'S0');

-- E (num4,name3,name4,num5)

insert into E values (1,'Teresa','Reino',1);
insert into E values (6,'Maria','Filo',1);
insert into E values (7,'Francisca','Ordem',6);
insert into E values (8,'Rita','Ordem',6);
insert into E values (9,'Beatriz','Ordem',6);
insert into E values (10,'Sofia','Filo',1);
insert into E values (11,'Bea','Ordem',10);

-- C (num5,num3,name2,num4)
insert into C values (2,1,'Cao',9);
insert into C values (1,2,'Gato',8);
insert into C values (1,3,'Golfinho',7);
insert into C values (3,4,'Peixe',11);

 -- B (Num1,name,Num2, Num3) 
insert into B values (1,'Maria',1,1);
insert into B values (2,'Jorge',2,1);
insert into B values (3,'Teresa',2,1);
insert into B values (4,'Rui',3,1);
insert into B values (1,'Fran',3,3);
insert into B values (2,'Juliett',3,3);
```

Comment: Você não consegue postar a estrutura de tabelas com os dados? Fica realmente difícil transpor todas as tabelas por imagens.

Comment: Postar imagens ao invés de escrever na publicação não é uma boa ideia. Dê uma olhada em como criar um [mcve], em [ask] e no [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/18246).

Comment: Já editei a pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a cláusula `NOT EXISTS` no `WHERE` para procurar um aquário sem vínculo:

```
SELECT cat.nome
  FROM cat_taxonomica cat
 -- Que não tenha um aquário sem vínculo
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM aquario a
                   -- Que não tenha um vínculo com a categoria inicial
                   WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                                      FROM especime esp
                                           INNER JOIN especie e ON e.id_especie = esp.id_especie
                                     WHERE esp.id_aquario = a.id_aquario
                                       AND e.id_cat = cat.id_cat))
```

> [**Subqueries com EXISTS or NOT EXISTS**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)
>
> Se a `subquery` retornar alguma linha, `EXISTS` é `TRUE`, e `NOT EXISTS` é `FALSE`

Obtemos o resultado:

```
 ___________
| nome      |
|___________|
| Carnivora |
|___________|
```